# Java Error : cannot invoke size() on the primitive type double

Tags: java, arraylist, double, size

I have been learning Java for about a week and I was working on a program that finds the average of any amount of numbers. But I faced a problem where it would divide every number by the total number, instead of dividing the sum of all values. I also tried finding the last value of the Array list and then divide it by the count. But it didn't work.

This is my code :

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.*;

public class Average {

    public static void main (String args[]){

        double  average, count, orig = (double) 0;
        double all =(double) 0;

        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

        ArrayList<Double> list = new ArrayList<Double>();

        while (input.hasNextDouble()) list.add(input.nextDouble());

        count = (double) list.size();

        for (Double x: list) {
            all += x;
            average = all/count;
            System.out.println(average);

            double e = average.get(average.size() - 1);
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

and the output is :

```
21
20
23
24
25
a
4.2
8.2
12.8
17.6
22.6
25.0
```

Comment: `average.get(average.size() - 1);` makes no sense since `average` is a `double`, not some kind of `List`

Comment: Why casting (`(double) 0;`) ??

Comment: Shouldn't you be iterating the list, adding each value to the sum and once you've done, divide it by the number of elements?  Why are you trying to do it from inside the loop?

Comment: I am not getting what are you trying to accomplish . Your Title does not go with your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are quite a few redundancies with your code.

```
double  average, count, orig = (double) 0;
```

can be written as:

```
double average, count, orig = 0.0d;
```

(you should consider checking float and decide which suits you better - doesn't really matter here)

Since java 1.7, you can declare lists in a shorter manner (search "diamond expression").

```
ArrayList<Double> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

In the line

```
double e = average.get(average.size() - 1);
```

you probably ment `list` instead of average, which should fix the error in the title.

Right now your code is printing average multiple times and only the last time is the real average of list items. Consider moving printing command of average out of for loop.

try this:

```
for (Double x: list)
    {
        all += x;

    }
average = all/count;
System.out.println(average);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick response man, appreciate it :). But if I change average to list in "double e = average.get(average.size() - 1);" it prints out every number divided by the count, but I only want the total sum divided by the count.

Comment: then move the line `System.out.println(average);` out of the for loop scope. I edited my answer

Comment: I get it. I was looping when it was inside yea?

Comment: Yes, everything before the closing '}' will loop, so you were printing all the intermediate values. If this helped you, consider choosing this as an answer

Answer (score 1):

You cannot call size() method on primitive data type.It can be called on `java.util.List` ,etc. So your `double e = average.get(average.size() - 1);` makes no sense.

You can directly write:

```
average = all/count;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are keeping too much code in the loop.
While you iterate over the list of doubles, you only need to keep a running total. Afterwards, you should then compute the average as the sum of doubles divided by the size of the list.

Here is how to fix the loop:

```
for (Double x: list)
    {
        all += x;
     }
average = all/count;
System.out.println(average);


//These lines are not useful, so they are commented out.
//double e = average.get(average.size() - 1);
// System.out.println(e);
```